# How do I calculate the percentage of a line which falls in each of my multiple ring buffers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, intersection

I have lines around which I have created multiple ring buffers at several intervals. 
I have another line (call it the flight line) which in theory should overlap the original line. 
I need to work out how much of the flight line falls within each of the buffers of the original line. See attached picture.

[image]

So, my plan of attack was to do an intersect of the flight line with the buffer, creating a point output. I was then planning to do a 'Split Line at Point' then using the attribute table to work out the lengths.

However, when I do the intersect, points are not created at all of the intersections with the buffer, just some of them, randomly.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? 
Or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried spatial join? You can use merge rules to calculate sum of  the length of line field.

Comment: Could you replace your current picture with something that is much more zoomed in, please?

Comment: Absolutely.So the yellow line is the original line, buffers surrounding and the black line is the flight line.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to create a point output? Do the following:

- add a field and calculate the length of the "fligth line"
- intersect the "flight line" with the "buffer polygon"
- dissolve the "flight line buffer polygon line" depending on the "buffer polygon"
- calculate the length of the "flight line buffer polygon dissolve line"
- devide the length of the "flight line buffer polygon dissolve line" by the original length of the line

Comment: Thanks Alex, I needed the point output only so I could then split the line at the point. I'll have a go at your suggestion